# How can I make a pop-up that appears on the screen when I open my application?

Tags: android-studio

How can I make a pop-up that appears on the screen when I open my application? for example when i open camera, appears screen the pop up message.

Comment: tell us more or show an example what you want, because I understand you need regular AlertDialog which is added inside onCreate() method of activity for example

Comment: Of course, please don't be offended. So what I need is; When I open the camera, I want a pop up message to appear on the screen. In my project, the camera opens only when the button is pressed, if you do not press the button, the camera voltage is cut off and does not work. In this case, I want a pop-up that appears on the screen when the key is not pressed. For example, please try to turn on the camera again by pressing the button. I aim to write a message that I shared in the link to the screen.  https://xiaomi.eu/community/attachments/img_20191004_040733-jpg.26407/

Comment: As I understand the camera works only after pressing the button? besides the camera you also have other screens for example we have MainActivity-> some btn clicked - >CameraActivity or CameraFragment,  but the camera does not work(black screen) until I press the button on the camera screen? it's hard to understand what exactly you need without the code as you did))
as I wrote, if you need to show a dialog at startup, just write the dialog logic onCreate() method if this is an activity, but then i don't understand what is the difficulty in doing this, you can't make a dialogue?

Comment: @Yura
In fact, it is enough if I can write a pop-up message that appears on the screen only when the camera is turned on. But I have no idea how it's done.

Comment: @Yura ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

for (int i = 0; i < runningAppProcessInfo.size(); i++) {
  if(runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName.equals("com.the.app.you.are.looking.for") {
    // Do you stuff
  }
}                                                                                                                               
                 Yura how do I use this code in simple hellow world Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of dialog to make pop-ups in your app

Step 1: Make a new layout file.

Step 2: Add The View which you want on your layout file.

Step 3: Add this code in your onCreate();

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // you should set Id of your layout file here 
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.selection_theme);

myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable((new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)));
              
 myDialog.show();
```

And if you want to get Id of the Views on the dialog xml layout use

myDialog.R.id.Name_of_Your_View

if you want to close the pop up after you click on some view then use

myDialog.dismiss();

And of course you can name anything instead of myDialog,selection_theme etc